# How to Achieve a Smooth Transition on a Wall with Mesh-Reinforced Gypsum?

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster, renovation

I'm currently renovating a room in my home and have encountered a unique challenge. After removing the old paint and loose material, I discovered a section of the wall reinforced with mesh, covered by a thick layer of gypsum or a similar material.

My initial plan was to skim coat the entire wall for a paintable finish. However, I'm unsure how to handle the transition between the regular wall surface and the mesh-reinforced area.

There's a noticeable difference in thickness between the regular wall and the gypsum-reinforced area. How can I create a smooth transition here? I would prefer not to tear down the mesh.

I would appreciate any advice or techniques for dealing with this situation, especially from those who have faced similar challenges. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly normal if it's fiberglass (as in mesh tape for drywall) - would be a bit odd if it's metal mesh, but it appears to be falling apart the way fiberglass tape does.

Anyway, you don't tear it down, you build the wall surface up over it with joint compound and wide knives so that a smooth, wide hump envelops all the bits needing to be hidden, as well as the change of thickness. On the low side that might need to go out 16" or more to make the transition smooth.

You might start with scraping off some of the high parts of the half-fast job done so far, without scraping so deep as to get into the tape, if you don't want to mess with the tape.

Do not try to build up thick layers in one go. Lay on multiple thin layers, letting each one dry (or cure if you use hot mud for them) before adding another.

Comment: From my seat, it looks like there's a lot of loose stuff there, including the tape... it's not hard to build after you've chipped that mess out.